# laravel 5 relating many to many models by user input

Tags: php, laravel

I have two models cars and customers.
I can add new, update and delete and attach/detach them all works.
I want to allow the user to relate them to each other(many to many relation). The question is how I should do it? Do I need new route? or if statement on one of update routes? Both update routes(for cars and customers)? A new model for relation? I think I will need to CRUD them as well.